# tsconfig why do I see compileOptions at so many places instead of compilerOptions

Tags: typescript, tsconfig, compiler-options

I am migrating a project from javascript to typescript and was reading several blogs to understand how could I go about doing that. I wonder why do so many blogs use `compileOptions` instead of `compilerOptions`. On the official guide/docs I only find the later. My guess is older versions of typescript expected `compileOptions` and it was later renamed, however I am unable to find any source to confirm that from any source/docs.

Comment: "_why do so many blogs use `compileOptions` instead of `compilerOptions`_": To which URLs do you refer?

Comment: @jsejcksn one example: https://blog.logrocket.com/a-simple-guide-for-migrating-from-javascript-to-typescript/

Comment: I don't have enough info to be positive, but there are plenty of typos all over the internet, and I think this is an instance of that. Here are indexed queries on GitHub of the repository [code](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/search?q=%22compileOptions%22&type=code) and [issues](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/search?q=%22compileOptions%22&type=issues) for that string. It seems like a typo to me.